# You don't know what this means

Tags: riddle, word, knowledge, lateral-thinking

What name is missing from the second place in the following line?

> Rembrandt ? Heinrich

Replace the question mark.

Hint 2

> The good thing in lateral thinking (at least by my opinion) is that it allows you to think laterally if the puzzle is incomplete and again laterally if the puzzle is complete

Comment: Changing the puzzle causes old answers to appear obsolete and or incorrect..

Answer (score 3):

Obsolete as the question has been changed

---

The answer is

> 'de'

Because

> Heinrich Hofmann was a famous german painter, and is followed by the german for the: 'die'. Rembrandt is a dutch painter and therefore the ? is replaced by the dutch for the: 'de'

Comment: If Heinrich was rot13(znyr, jbhyqa'g vg or *qre*)?

Comment: @WeatherVane I think it should be yes. The question seems a bit underdeveloped IMO

Comment: Reverted to rot13. The new spoiler format is bad and confusing (click converts it to normal block-quote).

Comment: Incorrect. Look how you're dealing with the names. It's even more idiosynchratic than the puzzle itself....

Comment: @FIreCase I think it may be difficult to get this correct without another example. At the moment the only thing we have to go on is Heinrich die, perhaps any other person in the series would help (that’s if someone can be added of course)

Comment: I have to clarify sg.(Although it's clearly stated.)  It's just a line/row containing words. Do you see the word sequence/series somewhere?  And "Heinrich doesn't die". Use the hints and I'm 75% sure you'll get it.

Comment: @FIreCase tbh I still have no idea, might be too abstract for me lol. Im guessing its a sentence thats been translated or something? Not sure how to get this

Comment: :) In fact It's a single word association puzzle.No sentence. But positioning of words have a slight additional information .